# Ansible: how to convert list into integer

Tags: python, json, list, ansible, integer

i have the following json output

```
"lc_facts": {
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false, 
        "launch_configurations": [
            {
                "block_device_mappings": [
                    {
                        "device_name": "/dev/sda1", 
                        "ebs": {
                            "delete_on_termination": true, 
                            "volume_size": 40, 
                            "volume_type": "gp2"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
       ]
  }
```

The query below

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lc_facts.launch_configurations|json_query('[*].block_device_mappings[0].ebs.[volume_size]') | flatten }}"
```

gives

```
    "msg": [
    [40]
    ]
```

i want to convert into an integer so i can use this value. i tried everything, but all i want is to get number only without brackets. i also added `|int` in the end, but it gives me 0 value, which is weird.

please help, i am really in trouble.

Comment: what does this number represent ? is this the volume size ? and is your json structure always the same ?

Comment: it is the volume size. for this query, it will be same. but it can be changed

Comment: what can be changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Brackets create a list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-basics). `[[40]]` is a list of lists with one element `40`. The play below

```yaml
  - hosts: localhost
    vars:
      var1: [[40]]
    tasks:
      - debug: var=var1
      - debug: var=var1[0]
      - debug: var=var1[0][0]
```

a) gives abridged ([ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-stdout-callback)=default)

```yaml
{
    "var1": [
        [
            40
        ]
    ]
}
```

```yaml
{
    "var1[0]": [
        40
    ]
}
```

```yaml
{
    "var1[0][0]": "40"
}
```

b) gives abridged ([ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-stdout-callback)=yaml)

```yaml
  var1:
  - - 40
```

```yaml
  var1[0]:
  - 40
```

```yaml
  var1[0][0]: '40'
```

Comment: huge respect for you. i have no words to say thank you. excellent explanation as well.

Answer (score 2):

try taking the first element of the list with index [0].
Do it twice if the list is inside another list:

for msg = [40] use msg[0]

for msg = [[40]] use msg[0][0]

Answer (score 0):

```
def dict_to_obj(obj, data):
    for d in data:
        if isinstance(data[d], dict):
            setattr(obj, str(d), obj.__class__())
            dict_to_obj(getattr(obj, str(d)), data[d])
        else:
            setattr(obj, str(d), data[d])
    return obj

class Empty:pass
obj = Empty()
obj = dict_to_obj(obj,Your_JSON_object)
#Now here you get all json attributes as objects e.g.
#to get volume_size : 
print(obj.lc_facts.launch_configurations.block_device_mappings.ebs.volume_size)
# but for this to work, you need to restructure your json nested key-value pairs like 
# this :-
"launch_configuration" : {....}
# instead of this :-
"launch configuration" : [ {....} ]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for code. this will be helpful when i will try some python.